# Is there any way to track the execution of an IQueryable within C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I am currently performing maintenance on a legacy Web Forms Linq To SQL system.  The users are currently experiencing different exceptions on a daily basis. The main one is "The wait operation timed out" which is indicative of long running queries overloading the Database.

I have the elmah log of exceptions however just because a User experiences the error does not mean they caused it, so with Elmah I can't tell what those queries are.

I have tried using the SQL Server Profiler to track all the queries but there is too many,  and they do not provide a stack trace so I cannot locate where they were called from.

My system does however provide a wrapper for the DataContext, it looks like this:

```
public class DataAccess
{
    public DataContext DataContext { get; set; }

    public DataAccess(DataContext dataContext);

    public IQueryable<T> SelectAll<T>();

    public IQueryable<T> SelectAll<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);

    public T SelectSingle<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);

    public void DeleteItem<T>(T item);

    public void UpdateItem<T>(T item);

    public void AddItem<T>(T item);

    public void AddItems<T>(IEnumerable<T> items);
}
```

`DeleteItem`, `UpdateItem`, `AddItem` and `SelectSingle` all execute the Queries in their methods with `this.DataContext.SubmitChanges()` / `.FirstOrDefault()`.  **So I came up with the idea of programming a timer in these methods to track any long running queries and report them with the full stack trace of events.**

However, because it is read heavy, most of the queries in the system will use `SelectAll`, which will not execute in `DataAccess` and because there is calls to this method in every .aspx code file (of which there are hundreds).  It's not feasible to program a timer in everyone of these pages.

So my question is: Is there any way of timing all Queryable execution in the code so I can report it with the StackTrace OR can anyone think of a better way of finding out which pieces of code contain the bad Linq queries.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that your queries don't  enumerate the whole table and then filter the result.  So scan your code and make sure that you don't call ToList(),  ToArray(), etc before  the filter like singleordefault for example.
2. Use a sql profiler like this free one https://expressprofiler.codeplex.com/ to track your queries and you should be able to find the long queries and how long they take.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it does not really suit my question. I have already stated that an SQL profiler is not an option because it gives no stack trace. The code is too vast to check every page file for bad linq; I have checked the commonly used pages and the linq seems ok.

Comment: If you after just the timer,  you can use Stopwatch class which you start it before the call to your query and stop it after the end of the call,  then you will know how much time your query took. But you still can get somerhing from checking the sql profiler because that will tells you exactly what query was executed and what results set your query returned.